# Fix code request for 'Auto Fit Row Height Of Merged Cells' formula. VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, merge

The primary issue with this macro is that when the text is too long, the height of the merged cells becomes too large.

The thread on from the source(listed below), does not have any really satisfying solutions to the issue.

The merged cell takes info from several sources and includes 'char(10) spaces that make it difficult to create a single cell column for auto-fitting.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub AutoFitAll()
  Call AutoFitMergedCells(Range("a1:b2"))
   Call AutoFitMergedCells(Range("c4:d6"))
    Call AutoFitMergedCells(Range("e1:e3"))
End Sub

Public Sub AutoFitMergedCells(oRange As Range)
  Dim tHeight As Integer
  Dim iPtr As Integer
  Dim oldWidth As Single
  Dim oldZZWidth As Single
  Dim newWidth As Single
  Dim newHeight As Single
  With Sheets("Sheet4")
    oldWidth = 0
    For iPtr = 1 To oRange.Columns.Count
      oldWidth = oldWidth + .Cells(1, oRange.Column + iPtr - 1).ColumnWidth
    Next iPtr
    oldWidth = .Cells(1, oRange.Column).ColumnWidth + .Cells(1, oRange.Column + 1).ColumnWidth
    oRange.MergeCells = False
    newWidth = Len(.Cells(oRange.Row, oRange.Column).Value)
    oldZZWidth = .Range("ZZ1").ColumnWidth
    .Range("ZZ1") = Left(.Cells(oRange.Row, oRange.Column).Value, newWidth)
    .Range("ZZ1").WrapText = True
    .Columns("ZZ").ColumnWidth = oldWidth
    .Rows("1").EntireRow.AutoFit
    newHeight = .Rows("1").RowHeight / oRange.Rows.Count
    .Rows(CStr(oRange.Row) & ":" & CStr(oRange.Row + oRange.Rows.Count - 1)).RowHeight = newHeight
    oRange.MergeCells = True
    oRange.WrapText = True
    .Range("ZZ1").ClearContents
    .Range("ZZ1").ColumnWidth = oldZZWidth
  End With
End Sub
```

Source: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2342-excel-autofit-row-height-merged-cells.html?page_comment=2

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the line below:

```
oRange.Rows(oRange.Rows.Count).EntireRow.AutoFit
```

After:

```
oRange.MergeCells = True
oRange.WrapText = True
```

In your code above

Comment: Just curious, will `AutoFit` take effect after `MergeCells`?

Comment: @Prisoner only one way, test the code and see what happens (use a very long text as the **PO** asked)

Comment: This just autofits the text to a single line.